# Weighted average semi-parametric regression in R

Tags: r, regression, algorithms, nonparametric

Are there any packages that supports weighted average semi-parametric regressions in R? An example of such a regression is in the links below.

I see that there is package [GAM](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://eprints.lse.ac.uk/24504/1/dp599.pdf&ei=FOYoTqo0zdOAB8qn8Z8L&usg=AFQjCNGx4pn6837FopcKifg8qwK4d2Setg) in R for Generalized Additive Models. However, it is not clear to me whether this procedure is the same as weighted average semi-parametric regression. There is also a package called [SPM](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-nonparametric-regression.pdf)

Some background on semi-parametric methods as used by Connor is [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://eprints.lse.ac.uk/24504/1/dp599.pdf&ei=FOYoTqo0zdOAB8qn8Z8L&usg=AFQjCNGx4pn6837FopcKifg8qwK4d2Setg). This paper refers extensively to improvements in the methodology vs. a prior paper by Connor [here](http://sticerd.lse.ac.uk/dps/em/Em506.pdf)

Also, attached is a paper that discusses [non-parametric regressions in R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-nonparametric-regression.pdf)

Thank you

Comment: I took a quick glance at the article, there is no mention of bilinear regression in it. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @mpitkas, I updated the link to a paper that explicitly refers to bi-linear regression. This paper had referenced the prior paper. Hopefully this helps - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No it still doesn't.  The linked paper (Connor, Hagmann, Linton 2007) refers extensively to how it does things differently and presumably better than the bilinear approach taken in Connor and Linton (2007, forthcoming in the Journal of Empirical Finance).  Presumably *that* paper is the one to link to here.

Comment: I added the reference to the earlier paper as well. Thanks